# Fastest way to filter out pandas dataframe rows containing special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list special characters. For example

```
BAD_CHARS = ['.', '&', '\(', '\)', ';', '-']
```

I want to remove all the rows from a pandas dataframe column containing these special characters. currently I am doing the following

```
df = '''
        words  frequency
            &         11
    CONDUCTED          3
       (E.G.,          5
   EXPERIMENT          6
         (VS.          5
        (WARD          3
            -         14
        2006;          3
           3D          5
         ABLE          5
     ABSTRACT          3
  ACCOMPANIED          5
     ACTIVITY         11
           AD          5
       ADULTS          6
'''
for char in BAD_CHARS:
    df = df[~df['word'].str.contains(char)]

# Expected Result
        words  frequency
    CONDUCTED          3
   EXPERIMENT          6
           3D          5
         ABLE          5
     ABSTRACT          3
  ACCOMPANIED          5
     ACTIVITY         11
           AD          5
       ADULTS          6
```

First it is not working and secondly it is not fast i guess. So how can I do that in a faster way ? Thanks

Comment: @Zero mark it, please.

Comment: First, don't escape the braces. `BAD_CHARS = ['.', '&', '(', ')', ';', '-']`. Next, you can either use a character class, or use `re.escape`. Something like this. `df[~df['words'].str.contains("[{}]".format(''.join(BAD_CHARS)))]`

Comment: If you have issues copying that, just type it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need first escape values and then join by `|` and as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ pointed remove `\` from values in `BAD_CHARS`:

```
import re

BAD_CHARS = ['.', '&', '(', ')', ';', '-']
pat = '|'.join(['({})'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in BAD_CHARS])

df = df[~df['words'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df)
          words  frequency
1     CONDUCTED          3
3    EXPERIMENT          6
8            3D          5
9          ABLE          5
10     ABSTRACT          3
11  ACCOMPANIED          5
12     ACTIVITY         11
13           AD          5
14       ADULTS          6
```

because this return empty frame:

```
df[~df['word'].str.contains('|'.join(BAD_CHARS))]
```

Comment: It returns empty frame :(

Comment: The question was closed as a dupe, and I've addressed the specifics of their question** in a comment. Or else, I could have posted the answer myself :/

Comment: Thanks. How easy it was :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I dont understand `Or else, I could have posted the answer myself :/` Do you think I copy your comment answer? I use only part of comment - dont escape it, and add mentioned it.